# Adobe Photoshop: Join dozens of images consecutively in a vertical filmstrip fashion?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to create a pdf file from dozens of long vertical sequences of images that exceed 100 mb, not composite mind you! A long pdf from huge long 1000 x 999999... who knows how long. I know that it needs to be a script to automate this task, but I don't know any.

Comment: Why would you use photoshop for this?

Comment: "who knows how long" - you, you should know that. there are finite amount of pictures with set resolution. That give you an answer to hwo long.

Comment: @joojaa There are websites for it, like photojoiner.net, https://merge.imageonline.co/ but after a certain amount it breaks every time. The same thing happened to a software which does the same thing called photojoiner. Trust me before resorting to photshop I've tried everything under the sun to my knowledge. IF you know such software then be sure to let me know :)

Comment: @SZCZERZO KŁY I don't know how to compute the dimension after all the images have been stitched. You know it incredibly saddens me how anywhere I look there isn't any answer to this, and the only place where I could get answers I'm downvoted to the negatives.

Comment: @Antonio so will photoshop. What you need is aapplication that makes a pdf with several images. Indesign would be much better suited.

Comment: @joojaa Do you know any reason why it breaks? The software crashes, the websites breaks down. Thanks for the info, just one last request. Can you just tell me how to stitch them vertically in Indesign? Like where I need to go/click?

Comment: @Antonio Pictures have dimensions, you lenght of them all and that give you overall lenght needed. A big (in dimensions) files, even empty, will be resource heavy for Photoshop (and for any web service). The question you need to ask yourself is why you want a long ribbon file? What is the purpose? And can you do it that will be asier, fister and lighter to handle.

Comment: @SZCZERZO KŁY Okay, so the thing is some have slight variations in dimensions like (999x1405,1000x238,1000x3254) so this is the reason that auto-resize to the largest image is coveted in this process. These images are downloaded from a website which is an online book version of what I seek, so instead of reading the pages by clicking open one singe page at a time I thought I converting the whole as a pdf. The other gentlemen recommended Adobe Indesign, but I don't know how to do what I need to do, do you have any idea?

Comment: Ummm you can combine the pictures into regular book pdf. So each page is one single page. And that's all. There's no need to make a ribbon.

Comment: @SZCZERZO KŁY I know but then it doesn't align well because of the slight variation in dimensions, one's big while the other is small. I want all the images to align well, if one image is small or doesn't align then I hope some software is there to autoresize and stretch it to fit. Do you get what I'm saying? This same stuff can be done in online tools but there's a limit to how many you images you can do before it breaks down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this kind of border constraint you can not do it. There is simply a limit to how much data can be in one image. Your constrained by how much data each container format can show up.

So lets say the video is 10 minutes long at 30 fps and the video is 1080p then there is 10*60*30*1080 pixels in the height of the file thats 19 400 000 pixels high and the file would use 112 Gigabytes of video memory to view it (this would make most devices unable to open the file).

Since you want a file of reasonable size you can not save a file like this as the jpeg stream that youd use for compression is limitted to 65535 pixels in height (and width) zip stream might be possible but likely compressing it and uncompressing it is inpractical.

Also Photoshop has a hard limit of 300 000 pixels so even photoshop couldnt do this. Not even for minute of fullhd content.

So your pdf would need to consist of tiles of images, which is not something photoshop does. But indesign might.

So not only is this impractical for large files its downright impossible to get anybody to virw the files unless you split the images up... And impractical even so.

Comment: @SZCZERZO KŁY Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. Would you mind telling me how to do this process in Indesign, or even just putting some tutorial links would be helpful :)